# Need to add only business days

Tags: businesshours

In Opportunity i created a formula date field. in which i want only it take business days means like:`TODAY() + ( ( ( 0.7 * ( Total_Payback_Amount__c ) ) - Total_Collected_to_Date__c ) / Daily_Payment__c )` this formula i used  in formula date field.

Right now what is happening is like today is Wednesday and formula return  3 means Today + 3 = Saturday, **but it should be display the date of monday.**

Answer (score 0):

To get you started, try this well-known formula:

```
CASE( MOD( Date__c - DATE(1900, 1, 7), 7), 0, "Sunday", 1, "Monday", 2, "Tuesday", 3,
"Wednesday", 4, "Thursday", 5, "Friday", 6, "Saturday","Error")
```

Together with a case statement and a modulo operation, I'm sure you'll be able to build your formula!